# is there any meaningful difference between the two versions of failable initialisers

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I'm studying failable initialiser in swift and I have came up with two version for failable initialiser for the struct Animal. I was just wondering if there is any meaningful difference between the two version. If yes, how the difference might affect code execution? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
struct Animal{
    var species: String
    init?(name: String){
        species = name
        if species.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct Animal{
    var species: String
    init?(name: String){

        if name.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        species = name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In one you're setting your `var` and then making a comparison (which makes it slightly more costly), but the end result will be the same in either.